# Rails url helper not encoding ampersands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, url-encoding

So I'm trying to use a Rails URL helper (`page_url`) to create URLs that contain special characters, including ampersands.  Most cases work like you'd expect them to:

```
(rdb:1) page_url('foo', :host => 'host')
"http://host/pages/foo"
(rdb:1) page_url('foo_%_bar', :host => 'host')
"http://host/pages/foo_%25_bar"
```

But for some odd reason, ampersands are not escaped:

```
(rdb:1) page_url('foo_&_bar', :host => 'host')
"http://host/pages/foo_&_bar"
```

And if I pre-escape them, they get corrupted:

```
(rdb:1) page_url('foo_%26_bar', :host => 'host')
"http://host/pages/foo_%2526_bar"
```

`CGI::escape`, on the other hand, escapes them fine:

```
(rdb:1) CGI::escape('foo_&_bar')
"foo_%26_bar"
```

What's going on, and how do I work around this?  (With something nicer than `gsub('&', '%26')`, that is.)

Comment: Hmmm.. I can't actually find a rails helper specifically called page_url (looked on the apidock website) - are you sure that's the correct method-name? Do you mean url_for instead?

Comment: I have an ActiveRecord called "page", the _url helper for it is created automagically.

Comment: Ah - right. That didn't come through in your description :)

Comment: Added a bit more to my answer after digging deeper into the source code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can't tell you a nicer way to deal with it - but I can explain why it's happening.

Ampersands are not invalid characters for a URL. Otherwise you'd have problems with: "http://host/pages/foo?bar=baz&style=foo_style" or whatever.

Edit:
Digging deeper into the source code, it looks like Rails uses CGI.escape only on parameters.

The helper, url-generators use url_for (under the covers), which eventually calls: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Routing/Route/generate
Which calls stuff deep in the sprivate-methods of the source code... but eventually ends up calling CGI.escape
(first look in actionpack/lib/action_controller/routing/route.rb then in actionpack/lib/action_controller/routing/segments.rb )

End result is that on the url itself, rails uses URI.escape - which notably does not update ampersands at all:

```
>> CGI.escape('/my_foo_&_bar')
=> "%2Fmy_foo_%26_bar"
>> URI.escape('/my_foo_&_bar')
=> "/my_foo_&_bar"
```

There's currently nothing you can do about this without putting an actual feature-request onto the rails team.

...unless you have the option to choose not to use ampersands in your URLs
You can always gsub them out yourself for all URLs:

```
def my_clean_url(the_url)
   return the_url.gsub(/&/,'_')
end
>> my_clean_url('/my_foo_&_bar')
=> "/my_foo___bar"

page_url(my_clean_url('/my_foo_&_bar'))
```

Comment: The issue is that the & is used by the underlying (non-Ruby) app as a normal character, but many URL parsers see it as a parameter delimiter and chop up the URL when they see it.  Encoding it makes sure it stays intact.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks Taryn! I did a quick experiment by creating a new Rails 3 project with a simple Car resource and ran the ascii characters through it to see what gets encoded by Rails when I call car_path(some_ascii_char). ie. (1..256).map {|car| app.car_path(car.chr)} I found that the everything gets encoded except ! $ % & ' - , + * ( ) / : ; = @ . _ ~ Hence only % / ? & are likely to be problematic and need to be manually encoded.

Comment: How about just calling: 
     CGI.unescape(page_url('foo_%_bar', :host => 'host'))

Answer (score 11):

For all those who are trying to just encode anything other than a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and underscore:

```
URI.encode(string, /\W/)
```

Say you have some content which may contain e.g. ampersands and you want to use this content as `body` parameter for a `mailto` link: Without `/\W/`, the ampersand (which is a safe URI character) would not be encoded and therefore partially break the link.